# Intellij Project View Modules of Parent POM as own Project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm currently creating a parent pom and defining maven modules underneath it. With the current way I have Project view set up, It's placing the modules underneath the parent POM, and I have to drill down on them individually.  Is there a way to have them in their own project so I don't have to drill down within each directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to

```
Settings -> Maven -> Importing
```

and play with these to find out what suits you.

```
Create IntelliJ IDEA modules for aggregator projects (with 'pom' packaging)
Create module groups for multi-module Maven projects
```

See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-importing.html for details.

Comment: Not exactly working for me, but will upvote as I think it's along the right lines.